# Subgraph returning null for some addresses

Tags: tokens, openzeppelin, balances, the-graph, subgraph

I have deployed a version of the `open-zeppelin-subgraph` (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-subgraphs) and I am tracking `ERC20`, `ERC721` and `ERC1155` tokens.

I am using this query:

```
    {
        account(id: "${walletAddress}") {
            ERC20balances {
                id
                value
            }
            ERC721tokens {
                id
                identifier
            }
            ERC1155balances {
                token {
                    id
                    identifier
                }
                valueExact
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that instead of getting empty arrays for wallets that does not have a balance of the tokens I am tracking, I am getting this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "account": null
  }
}
```

Why is this happening only for some addresses? I think this is the format I should get no matter what addresses I use:

```
{
  "data": {
    "account": {
      "ERC20balances": [],
      "ERC721tokens": [],
      "ERC1155balances": []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It happens when the subgraph is not fully synced. Could it be the case?

Comment: In this case I have checked that the subgraph is fully synced with the blockchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`open-zeppelin-subgraph`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-subgraphs) uses this function every time an `account` takes part in a transaction or event you are tracking in your subgraph:

```
export function fetchAccount(address: Address): Account {
    let account = new Account(address)
    account.save()
    return account
}
```

By "taking part" I mean being a sender or a receiver of a token or being a proposer or a voter. This will vary depending on the type of contracts you are tracking.

So, if the `account` you are looking for has never taken part in any transaction or event of the ones you are indexing, that `account` will appear as `null` because it has never been saved to the database as an `account` entity.